# how to place text and a tabbed navigation next to each other

Tags: html, css, haml

**I have written a text inside h2 and next to that i want to show a tabbed navigation but that tabbed navugation is not being placed next to it ,its going below h2 as shown in following image inside that gray box:**

[image]

Following is my code for html page:

```
<header>

   <h2>
     Corporate
     jobpost
   </h2>


    <div id='tabjob'>

         <ul>
           <li>
              <a class='innertab selectprofile' href='#YourJobposts'>Your Jobposts</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a class='innertab signupprofile' href='#OtherJobposts'>Other Jobposts</a>
           </li>
           <li>

              <a class='innertab signupprofile' href='#Appliedfor'>Applied for</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

header is the thing which is in gray color in the image.Inside this header i want to show text ,next to that tabbed navigation and at the corner that button

---

Following is my CSS for this tabbed navigation:

```
#tabjob
{
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-left:10px;
    height:0px;

}

.innertab
{
    background-color: rgba(142, 194, 218, 0.3);display: block;height: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;text-align: center;
    width: auto;float: left;font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;

  text-shadow: #eee 0px 0px 2px;
}
#tabjob ul li
{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say which HTML is generated from the haml. Can you paste the page into http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: i have edited my answer and put html instead of haml code

Comment: sorry for that h2 thing..edited again

Comment: try this fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/AMAVV/ just add CSS `float:left` to `h2` tag

Comment: @Murtaza: Why isn't that an answer?

Comment: i can add it my friend @AaronDigulla

Comment: hii you can vote and mark it as answer now.. please find my answer below with respect to my comment.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already posted the answer in comments just adding the details of the answer here.

[DEMO is HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AMAVV/1/)

since your `h2` tag and all heading tags are block element in HTML it take the complete width available.

so to avoid `h2` tag to take complete width just add {float:left} to this element

Make sure you apply this style to specific `h2`  only otherwise your HTML will mess up. is you have used more than one `h2` tags on the page.

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="floatTag">Corporate jobpost</h2>
    <div id='tabjob'>
         <ul>
             <li>
                <a class='innertab ' href='#YourJobposts'>Your Jobposts</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class='innertab ' href='#OtherJobposts'>Other Jobposts</a>
              </li>
              <li>

                <a class='innertab ' href='#Appliedfor'>Applied for</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tabjob
{
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-left:10px;
    height:0px;
}

.innertab
{
    background-color: rgba(142, 194, 218, 0.3);display: block;height: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;text-align: center;
    width: auto;float: left;font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;

  text-shadow: #eee 0px 0px 2px;
}
#tabjob ul li
{
 display:block;
}

h2.floatTag{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block` for both the h2 and the tabjob:

```
h2, #tabjob { display: inline-block }
```

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/2774902

Answer (score 1):

`ul` and `div` are block elements which means they always go below whatever is before them:

```
 a<div>x</div>
```

would give you two lines. Try

```
 a<div style='display: inline'>x</div>
```

Comment: The `<div id='tabjob'>` is outside of the `h2` element. Move it inside.